# Can I place the rubiks3cube pieces in the distorted position I intend to get?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, rubiks-cube

Right now I am trying to get the distorted position like this: in each face only one diagonal is solved and no similar colour is on a face other than the diagonal pieces mentioned previously. For example: If I am looking at the white face, there should exactly be two corner pieces in that face correctly oriented, and no other white piece should be there. If there is one what will be the algorithm to get there?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.  Here's one algorithm (found [here](http://rubiksolve.com/cubesolve.php)): U F' D' R' B L F L2 F' U F2 U' R2 B2 D2 L2 U' B2 D F2 B2.

Comment: please give an image of positions you gave, i am not getting it.

Comment: http://cube.crider.co.uk/visualcube.php?size=150&pzl=3&alg=U%20F%27%20D%27%20R%27%20B%20L%20F%20L2%20F%27%20U%20F2%20U%27%20R2%20B2%20D2%20L2%20U%27%20B2%20D%20F2%20B2&fmt=png.  The back should look similar.